# Prove a given distance function is in fact a metric: $ d(f,g) = \sup\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)| $

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $C(X)$ be the set of all continuous and bounded functions with domain $X$. If $f,g\in C(X)$ define the distance between these functions by:
$$ d(f,g) = \sup\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)| $$
To prove $d$ is a metric, we have to show it satisfies $4$ properties:
$$ d(f,g)\geq0 $$
$$ d(f,g)=0 \quad\text{iFF}\quad f(x)=g(x) $$
$$ d(f,g) = d(g,f) $$
$$ d(f,g) \leq d(f,h)+d(h,g) $$
I showed the first three without much difficulty, so my question is related to proving the last property.

To do this, I let $f,g,h \in C(X)$ and fixed $x_0\in X$. Then by the triangle inequality for real numbers we know that:
$$ |f(x_o)-g(x_o)|\leq|f(x_0)-h(x_0)|+|h(x_0)-g(x_0)| \quad \ \forall \  x_0\in X $$
If the above statement is true for all $x_o \in X$ that it must be true that we can simply take the supremums of both sides of the inequality and it still holds true.

I'm not quite convinced of this logic, however, because couldn't the given distances be dependent on different points (i.e. maybe $d(f,g)=k$ occurs at $x_o$ while $d(g,h)=l$ occurs at $x_1$. If this were the case, I don't believe my argument holds up. However, I'm also not sure what else to try. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: That is a frequently used argument. For all $x_0$ is $|f(x_o)-g(x_o)|\leq|f(x_0)-h(x_0)|+|h(x_0)-g(x_0)| \le d(f, h) + d(h, g)$, therefore ...

Comment: so my argument is valid if I just take the supremum of both sides and simplify?

Comment: just saw the answer on the other question - thanks for the help I think I can see how to finish my proof from here